# The attached property Resources was not found in UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, wpftoolkit

During adding resources for my user control I get the error above. What may be the problem ?

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="PartitionManager.DocStorageView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:WpfToolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"
             xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <UserControl.Resources></UserControl.Resources>
    <WpfToolkit:DataGrid
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DocStorageInfos}"
        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  SelectionMode="Extended"
        CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False"
        CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="False"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" MaxWidth="750">
        <WpfToolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
            <WpfToolkit:DataGridCheckBoxColumn
                Header="Select"
                Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected}"/>
            <WpfToolkit:DataGridTextColumn
                Header="InterestingName" 
                Binding="{Binding Path=InterestingName}"/>
        </WpfToolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
    </WpfToolkit:DataGrid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: I removed the line
xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
as i didn't seem to need this namespace. (It also isn't referenced standard upon creating a new usercontrol).
I rebuild and then it compiled. I entered the namespace back in to confirm that this was the problem.
It still builded correctly.
My conclusion is therefore that there may have been be a problem in compiling the xaml here, although the code
should have been compiled without error.
In this particular case it is resolved, but if others encounter the same issue it may be usefull to address that.

Comment: Well posting your code/XAML would be a better idea rather than guessing here

Comment: loo large to post at once. <UserControl x:Class="PartitionManager.DocStorageView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:WpfToolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"
             xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d"

Comment: AutoGenerateColumns="False" MaxWidth="750">
        <WpfToolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
            <WpfToolkit:DataGridCheckBoxColumn
    Header="Select"
    Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected}"/>
            <WpfToolkit:DataGridTextColumn
    Header="InterestingName" 
    Binding="{Binding Path=InterestingName}"/>
        </WpfToolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
    </WpfToolkit:DataGrid>
</UserControl>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you possibly mess with the inheritance in code-behind?

Your class needs to inherit from UserControl:

```
 public partial class DocStorageView : UserControl
 { /*...*/ }
```

Comment: Hi H.B Please don't bash me for asking especially when I just want to address a problem and provide comments on a possible answer as well.

Comment: I am playing around with code from http://blog.smoura.com/wpf-toolkit-datagrid-part-ii-custom-styling/

Comment: I cant vote you up but you are right the DocStorageView didn't inherit from UserControl, similar to TeamView in the provided code on smoura's blog